# ENTRYPOINT with environment variables and overridable CMD

Tags: docker

This allows `$ENV_VAR` to be passed to `foo`

```
ENTRYPOINT /usr/bin/foo $ENV_VAR
```

This does not, because the literal string "$ENV_VAR" is passed, not the contents of the environment variable.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/foo", "$ENV_VAR"]
```

This allows overriding of CMD

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/foo"]
CMD ["--some-flag"]
```

This does not allow CMD to get to entrypoint. It *appears* to run it in two separate commands. ie: `sh /usr/bin/foo && sh --some-flag`

```
ENTRYPOINT /usr/bin/foo
CMD --some-flag
```

How do I make an ENTRYPOINT that uses environment variables and has an overrideable CMD? Ideally with the form as follows

*note: this does not work*

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/foo", "$ENV_VAR"]
CMD ["--some-flag"]
```

Comment: What about using the shell form for ENTRYPOINT and the array form for CMD?

Comment: you can use a script as the entrypoint and call your env within

Answer (score 3):

> note: this does not work
>
> ```
> ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/foo", "$ENV_VAR"]
> CMD ["--some-flag"]
> ```

That will run foo with `$ENV_VAR` as the first arg and `--some-flag` as the second arg. What you want is `$ENV_VAR` to be translated to the environment variable value, and that's done by a shell. The json syntax to ENTRYPOINT/CMD explicitly disables the shell, so it would be up to your executable to expand that value.

---

If you try to change ENTRYPOINT to the shell syntax with:

```
ENTRYPOINT /usr/bin/foo "$ENV_VAR"
CMD ["--some-flag"]
```

You'll find docker translates this to running:

```
/bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/foo \"$ENV_VAR\"" "--some-flag"
```

And if you look at the documentation on the `-c` option, you'll see that this only takes a single arg. So this option will not work for the `--some-flag` option which is being passed outside of the quotes.

---

The easiest solution is to move it to a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/foo "$ENV_VAR" "$@"
```

Copy that as entrypoint.sh into your container:

```
COPY entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod 755 /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["--some-flag"]
```

Note that the chmod command is only needed if you cannot make your script executable on all build hosts/code repositories (sometimes seen with windows users).